# Eclipse - Search arrow icons

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there any of disabling the yellow arrow that shows up when you perform a search in eclipse ? I was debugging my program earlier and i couldn't find my breakpoints, only to realize a couple of minutes later that they were being hidden behind eclipse arrows.

I know that the arrow goes away when you remove the matches from the search view, but is there a way of completely disabling the arrow from being shown ?

EDIT: Same goes for the green triangle for @Override

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to: Preference -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Annotations then select the Annotation you would like to remove from the list of annotation types. Uncheck the 'Vertical ruler' checkbox and apply the changes.
Hope this helps.

Comment: That's just what i needed! Thanks.